# Get array object's proprieties in one function React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have `avg[]` array with one object and `avgphone, avgemail and avgemail` object's proprieties. How can I get `avgphone, avgemail and avgemail` values in one function? It work ok, but it doesn't seems efficient,

```
AvgPhone = () => {
    const nr = this.state.avg.map( (t, idx) => (
        t.avgphone||0
    ))
    return nr;
}
AvgEmail= () => {
    const nr = this.state.avg.map( (t, idx) => (
        t.avgemail||0
    ))
    return nr;
}
AvgLiveChat= () => {
    const nr = this.state.avg.map( (t, idx) => (
        t.avglive||0
    ))
    return nr;
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output like? Do you want three different arrays? or single array og objects with these three as keys?

Comment: I want avgphone, avgemail and avgemail values separate. For now I call {this.AvgPhone()}, {this.AvgEmail()}, {this. AvgLiveChat()} to get the values

Comment: If there is just one single element in that array why do you bother?
`const { avgphone = 0, avgemail = 0, avglive = 0 } = { ...avg[0] };` :)  If your case is different then you should clarify this in your question. There are many options in order to what you want to do here.

Comment: @devserkan as I've described I have only one element in the array...but I want to clean the code because I have more arrays like avg[]

Comment: Then update your question with the overall picture and requirements. This helps you to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `avg[]` array with one object, you can use one function for this like:

```
const Avg = () => this.state.avg.map(({ avgphone,avgemail,avglive}) => ({
   avgphone: avgphone || 0,
   avgemail: avgemail || 0,
   avglive: avglive || 0
}))[0];
```

and then assign the values to a variable like this:

```
const {avgphone, avgemail, avglive} = Avg();
console.log( avgphone, avgemail, avglive )
```

**DEMO:**

```js
const arr = [{avgphone:1, avgemail:2, avglive: 3}]
const Avg = () => arr.map(({ avgphone,avgemail,avglive}) => ({ avgphone: avgphone || 0, avgemail: avgemail || 0, avglive: avglive || 0 }))[0];

const {avgphone, avgemail, avglive} = Avg();
console.log( avgphone, avgemail, avglive )
```

EDIT:

**Updated for a Class Component**

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.Avg = this.Avg.bind(this);
  }

   Avg() {
      return this.state.avg.map(({ avgphone, avgemail, avglive }) => ({
         avgphone: avgphone || 0,
         avgemail: avgemail || 0,
         avglive: avglive || 0
      }))[0]
   }

   render() {

      const {avgphone, avgemail, avglive} = this.Avg();
      console.log( avgphone, avgemail, avglive )

      return (...);
   }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank! How can I rewrite `const {avgphone, avgemail, avglive} = Avg();` for a Class Component, because the code above is for functional components I think

Comment: This should work for class components also. You will just need to create a new method named `Avg` outside the `render` without using `const` and inside the render or where you need the values you can get them by calling the `Avg()` function.

Answer (score 0):

with one `forEach` loop you can combine all in one object.

```js
const avg = [{ avgphone: 2, avgemail: 1 }, { avglive: 5 }];

const res = {AvgPhone: [], AvgEmail: [], AvgLiveChat: []};
avg.forEach(t => {
  res.AvgPhone.push(t.avgphone || 0);
  res.AvgEmail.push(t.avgemail || 0);
  res.AvgLiveChat.push(t.avglive || 0);
});

console.log(res);
```